# How to display term description in empty terms archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, terms, description, taxonomy

I list all terms from a taxonomy, even the empty ones, but I found out that at least in 2010/2011 themes I got a 404-like message, the default seems to only display the term description when at least one post is using it [#](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-visit-a-taxonomy-archive#post-1988573)

Filters seems the best thing but I can't find the right one.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Have you tried to move the archive header just before the `if ( have_posts() )`?

Comment: That will do it, but you'll still get the "nothing found" message below the header. Is there a way to prevent that?